# In C++, how can I generate a random number that falls between two ranges?

Tags: c++, random, generator

How can I write code to generate a random number that falls between two different ranges?

Example: Generate a random number that is between 5 and 7 or between 10 and 12. Possible outcomes are 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, or 12.

Comment: [Give this a read.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: It would have taken a fraction of the time to just google "C++ random number in range"

Comment: There are a couple of options depending on the kind of distribution you want. E.g. You could generate 1 number to choose which of the 2 ranges you want, then a second to choose a number from the selected range. Obviously this could skew the results with different size ranges. Alternatively: map the separate ranges to a new range which has "size" = sum(size of base ranges). Generate a number for the new range, and map the result back to one of the original ranges. (NOTE: Again results may be skewed if any of your ranges overlap.)

Comment: Commenters seem to conveniently gloss over the detail that it's not about a single range. All those downvotes... :(

Comment: Everyone who ever thinks about these things would do well to watch this great talk by an expert: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY

Comment: @aho Thanks! Cool video! I have noticed that rand() is not the most effective random number generator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>**UPDATE** Second implementation added below</sup>

---

If you want to make this generic, you'll have to code it.

Two options come to mind:

- <strike>discrete_distribution (just feed it 5,6,7,10,11,12)</strike>
- generate numbers [0..6) and index into an array `int arr[]={5,6,7,10,11,12}`

The second:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/549f23b3f8c1f651)</kbd>**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> arr = {5,6,7,10,11,12};

    mt19937 prng { random_device {} () };
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, arr.size()-1);

    int i = 10;
    while (i--)
        std::cout << arr[dist(prng)] << " ";
}
```

Prints

```
5 5 6 12 11 6 11 12 5 12
```

Or, similar of course

---

### UPDATE

An alternative implementation that will scale for many segments or large segments, by using Boost Interval Container Library to efficiently represent the intervals that make up the domain:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8ed173b8f22e9ba)</kbd>**

```
template <typename T = int>
struct uniform_draw {

    using set  = boost::icl::interval_set<T>;
    using ival = typename set::interval_type::type;

    uniform_draw(std::initializer_list<ival> data) 
        : set_(make_set(data)), dist_(0, set_.size() - 1)
    { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, uniform_draw const& ud) {
        return os << ud.set_ << " (#samples:" << ud.set_.size() << ")";
    }

    template <typename Engine>
    T operator()(Engine& engine) {
        uintmax_t index = dist_(engine);

        std::cout << " - index: " << index << " against " << set_ << "\n";

        // I think this can be optimized. I just don't know how to elegantly do that / yet
        for (auto& iv : set_) {
            std::cout << " - index: " << index << " against " << iv << "\n";
            if (index > size(iv)) {
                index -= size(iv);
            } else {
                return iv.lower() + index;
            }
        }

        throw std::range_error("uniform_draw");
    }

private:
    set make_set(std::initializer_list<ival> data) {
        set r;
        for (auto& el : data)
            r.insert(el);
        return r;
    }

    set const set_;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist_; // TODO make_unsigned<T>?
};
```

Use it like your usual distribution:

```
mt19937 mt { random_device {} () };

uniform_draw<int> dist { {5, 7}, {10, 12} };

std::cout << dist << "\n";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << "RESULT: " << dist(mt) << "\n";
```

Prints e.g.:

```
{[5,7)[10,12)} (#samples:4)
7 7 6 11 6 6 7 7 7 6
```

Comment: Freaky. The only difference between this and what I was about to post was the `using namespace std;` the name of the vector, and I used a `for` loop.

Comment: This answer requires large arrays. what if the ranges are too large? I am sure that there is a simple solution that does not require such arrays. But when I write it down it will be too late, so I give up. :d

Comment: @A.S.H First sentence: "If you want to make this generic, you'll have to code it." - there's a lot of ways. Do you really  want this? I can code it for you live in ~20 minutes: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Comment: @A.S.H The OP asked a specific question and this provides an answer to it. If he has large, cumbersome arrays to deal with, then he should say so in the question. sehe, I don't think your `discrete_distribution` suggestion is correct, that takes an array of weights, not the outcomes.

Comment: @Praetorian you can supply identical weights, but yeah, it was a brainfart because it still requires mapping the outcome domain

Comment: @Praetorian I dont want to miss sehe's spectacle. This guy is impressive, and I do respect his skills. Anyway, the OP didnt even say that they wanted a uniform distribution! so what is wrong for instance with Barmar's answer??

Comment: @A.S.H Here's a simplistic method that will scale decently. **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8ed173b8f22e9ba)** It can be optimized a bit, using the more obscure APIs from Boost ICL to quickly locate the indexed element, but for now, I'll leave this as inspiration.

Comment: Good job, and nice spectacle :). Well, now that it's over, let me clarify that my idea was actually much simpler. Quickly, in pseudo code: 1) pick x uniformly from a range that is as wide as the union of the two ranges  2) check the result against max(range 1). 3) if <= take x as is; if not, take x -  max(range 1) + min(range 2) + 1. It was pretty much your first idea, but without the need for the arrays :)

Comment: Anyway, + for sure :)

Comment: @A.S.H Actually, IMO that's not much simpler: it's exactly what I wrote. Only, I didn't have to think of the most efficient way to store the intervals (generically!) and test the interval combining, output intervals etc. Anyhoops: **[recorded livestream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/impl-uniform-random-draw-from-discrete-set/)**

Comment: Yes, I dont doubt that. I only said we dont need the arrays. You did not have to take it to the extreme ground of genericity. But that was a nice exercise anyway. Kudos :)

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense and is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a random number `0` or `1`. If this number is `0`, pick a random number in the first range, otherwise pick a random number in the second range.

If you want each number in the two ranges to have equal probability, you could weight the first decision based on the sizes of the two ranges.

Comment: If the ranges are not equal in size, this will not result in a uniform distribution. But the OP did not explicitly state it anyway, they just wanted random, so this will be random..

Comment: That's the same answer as Jared previously posted (and deleted)

Comment: @A.S.H I added a comment about weighting the first choice based on the sizes of the two ranges.

Comment: I deleted it since it was redundant in light of this answer.  OP has since added a lot of clarifications to the question

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this. Let's say your two ranges are [minA, maxA] and [minB, maxB] where maxA < minB (if not just swap the two ranges)

Solution 1:

```
1) Generate a random number X in [minA, maxB] first
2) if X falls (maxA,minB) goto 1)
3) At this point X is the output
```

Solution 2 (more efficient especially if the gap between the two ranges is big):

```
1) rangeA = maxA - minA, rangeB = maxB - minB;
2) generate a random number X within [0,rangeA+rangeB]
3) if X < rangeA then output minA+X else minB+X
```